# Cypress - wait for the API response and verify UI changes

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a component that I want to cover with some e2e tests. This component takes the URL provided by the user in the input, calls the API after the button click  and then returns the shortened version of that URL. After that, shortened url is added to the list  below the input on the UI and makes some localStorage assertion. I want Cypress to wait for the API response and only then check the UI if the list item was added. I made this working but I hardcoded the wait time in the `wait()` method. How Can I achieve that programatically ?

```
describe("Shortener component", () => {
  it("Should add the list item and data to localStorage", () => {
    cy.visit("http://127.0.0.1:5500"); //Live server extension address

    cy.get("#url-input").type("https://facebook.com");
    cy.get("#form-submit-button").click();

    // wait for the api response and make sure that the value has been added to the localStorage
    cy.wait(40000); //todo - wait for the api response instead of hardcoding the wait time
    const localStorageData = localStorage.getItem("linksData");
    if (JSON.parse(localStorageData)) {
      expect(JSON.parse(localStorageData)[0].inputValue).to.eq(
        "https://facebook.com"
      );
    }

    // check if the new list item with the corrct value has been addded
    cy.get(".shortener-component__list-item")
      .contains("https://facebook.com")
      .should("be.visible");

    //validation mesasge should not be visible
    cy.get("#validationMesage")
      .contains("Please add a valid link")
      .should("not.be.visible");
  });
});
```

I tried with `intercept()` however I failed. Not sure how to make it working. I also saw some similar SE topics on that but it did not help me.

Any ideas / examples apreciated :)

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the order of events you've given

1. short URL returned
2. added to localStorage
3. added to list

just change the order of feature testing

1. test list - it is last event, but has retriable commands (you can increase the timeout)
2. now test localStorage, if UI has the short URL so will localStorage

```js
cy.contains('.shortener-component__list-item', 'https://facebook.com', { timeout: 40000 })
  .then(() => {

    // nested inside .then() so that the above passes first

    const localStorageData = localStorage.getItem("linksData");
    const linksData = JSON.parse(localStorageData);
    expect(linksData).not.to.eq(undefined);
    expect(linksData[0].inputValue).to.eq("https://facebook.com");
  })
```

---

Alternatively, to make use of retry and timeout on the localStorage check,

```js
cy.wrap(localStorage.getItem("linksData"))
  .should('not.eq', undefined, { timeout: 40000 }) // will retry the above until true
  .then(data => JSON.parse(data))
  .should(parsedData => {              
    expect(parsedData.inputValue).to.eq("https://facebook.com");
  });
```

I guess you should also start the test with

```
cy.clearLocalStorage("linksData")
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for Your answer. It works and looks  really nice :) Thanks for the useful tricks

Answer (score 1):

There're examples in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Waiting-on-a-request), it only takes some reading and experimentation.

In general, you need three commands: `cy.intercept()`, `.as()`, and `cy.wait()`:

```
cy.intercept(your_url).as('getShortenedUrl');
cy.wait('@getShortenedUrl');
```

you can also use `.then()` to access the interception object, e.g. a response:

```
cy.wait('@getShortenedUrl').then(interception => { });
```

or you can check something in the response using `.its()`:

```
cy.wait('@getShortenedUrl').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
```

The point is that after `cy.wait('@getShortenedUrl')`, the response has been received.

Comment: Hello. Thx for the answer. I tried something like this cy.intercept(
      `https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=https://facebook.com`
    ).as("getShortenedUrl");
    cy.wait("@getShortenedUrl", { timeout: 20000 }).then(() => {
      consiole.log("callback");
    });
and my plan was to check different cases in the `then` block but this code throws Timed out retrying after 20000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 20000ms for the 1st request to the route: getShortenedUrl. No request ever occurred.

Do You have any idas why this happens ?

Comment: I'd explore the URL, perhaps it doesn't match.